# Grails 'withTransaction' with alternate dataSource

Tags: spring, grails, grails-orm

Trying to figure out how to open a transaction with an alternate dataSource in grails.  I have the following dataSources defined...

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = "update"
    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE"
}

dataSource_ALT {
   dbCreate = "update"
   url = "jdbc:h2:mem:altDb;MVCC=TRUE"
}
```

I'm able to do this with the default dataSource...

```
Foo.withTransaction { status ->
    //...
}
```

But when I try and do it with the ALT dataSource, I get an exception - 'No transactionManager bean configured'...

```
Foo.ALT.withTransaction { status ->
   //...
}
```

Is there a way to start a transaction using a different dataSource?  I've done some digging around and haven't been able to find much.

Thanks!

Comment: I have not tried this, but if it is not supported it seems like a bug/missed requirement in adding multiple datasources in grails 2.  You will have to use a workaround of using `.withTransaction` against domain objects with only one datasource.

Comment: Does it work if you don't use the shortcuts? 

`def sessionFactory_ALT 

def doStuff(){
  def tx = sessionFactory_ALT.currentSession.beginTransaction()
  tx.commit()
  tx.rollback()
  etc...
}
 
`

Answer (score 0):

@Raphael Your suggestion does work.  I was able to go to the next step and get withTransaction working by assigning a transaction manager.  They seem to be created, just not attached.  They exist as Spring beans named something like transactionManager_ALT (in this example).  Not sure what actually creates them, and why they aren't attached to the GormStaticApi.

i.e. here you'd do:

```
Foo["ALT"].transactionManager = transactionManager_ALT
```

Probably will try to pick one domain class and assign all the different transaction managers, see if that works, then use that one domain class everywhere to start transactions.